# Use OneDrive file picker without user logging in every time

Tags: javascript, onedrive

I've integrated the OneDrive file picker as described in https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/js-v7/js-picker-open.htm, but every time the file picker is opened the user is asked for a password even when the user is logged in according to the login screen (it shows the name and email address and says "Signed in"). The demo button on the above mentioned page works in the same way, asking for a password every time. Is there any way to have the file picker skip the login page for a user already logged in?

Comment: The picker is supposed to only show the account chooser the first time, and then cache the account that was chosen. I just tried this with my account, and it worked as I expected. Can you confirm that even after selecting an account and seeing the picker, then going back, it asks you to choose an account each time?

Comment: The first time I get the account chooser. If I'm already logged in clicking the account name will then take me directly to the file picker. The next time it doesn't show the account picker but a login screen with my name and email populated followed by a line saying 'Signed in'. I have to enter my password to proceed even though it says I'm logged in. This happens every time.

Comment: @hjhlarsen I have noticed the same issue where it will not keep you logged in when using a business account (works fine with a personal account). I created a ticket describing this issue here: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/502. Also, as a workaround click the back button the second time you open the file picker and then select your account and it will not ask for your password.

Comment: I have been actively on the phone with microsoft tech support for a few months about this. I don't think it supports directly sending in the user. but hopefully they can release an update that does.